# Is it possible to display an in-line image?

Tags: textbox, livecode

Article http://runrev.com/newsletter/june/issue135/newsletter4.php shows how to display a table in a text field. Is it as well possible to display in-line images?

Comment: Yes it's possible. http://lists.runrev.com/pipermail/use-livecode/2012-July/175056.html or http://forums.runrev.com/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=5780 should get you going

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to mess with the htmltext of the field in order to insert the online images, but it can be done. Put the htmltext of the field into a variable, then insert a line of html, as in

```
put "<img src=" & quote & "http://www.site.com/image.png" & quote & ">" after line x of tHtmlText
```

and then set the htmltext of the field back to tHtmlText

Answer (score 0):

If the image is in your stack, you can use

```
put "%" into fld 1
set the imageSource of char 1 of fld 1 to 1014
```

Where % is an arbitrary character and 1014 is the image id of an arbitrary image. You can set the imageSource of any character in a field.